# Failed to deserialize creator identity, err The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to provide node SDK's for my existing blockchain application(modified balance transfer). i started my node server and while query or invoke the transaction using the restclient/postman, i am facing error as mentioned below in the node server terminal,

> error: [client-utils.js]: **sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected:
>   Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err The
>   supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate
>   signed by unknown authority** at new createStatusError
>   (/scratch/node_SDK/fabric-test/nodejs/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
>   at
>   /scratch/node_SDK/fabric-test/nodejs/node_modules/**grpc**/src/client.js:584:15

Can anybody please help me on this?

Comment: i'm facing the same problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: No, Even i dint get solution for this case, facing the same

Comment: In the meantime, I solved it by deleting all the cryptographic material from .hfc-key-store and /tmp/fabric-client-kvs (used by the explorer)

Comment: Thank for the information. I also try the same when resuming that one